# Java String Literal Pool

Tags: java, string, literals, pool

Let's say we have the following code

```
String x = new String("xyz");
String y = "abc";
x = x + y;
```

A friend of mine says that 4 objects are created in total, where I say that only 3 are created. Can someone explain what's going on in the background? I've read about String Literal Pool, but I can find an answer for this.

My explanation for the creation of the 3 object is as follows: one in the String Literal Pool at compile time ("abc"), and two at runtime on the heap ("abc" and x + y)

Comment: Which JVM are you talking about? It's probably implementation-specific.

Comment: regardless of the JVM, how could 4 objects be created? what will be the fourth object?

Comment: yep theres three, "xyz", "abc" and "xyzabc".

Comment: You missed the `new String`

Comment: @Arvind what do you mean by "You missed the new String". The effect of new String is that it creates a new object at runtime on the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 objects are created as follow

```
// 1. "xyz" in the literal pool
// 2. a new String object which is a different object than "xyz" in the pool
String x = new String("xyz");

// 3. "abc" in the literal pool
String y = "abc";

// 4. new String object
x = x + y;
```

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get it. This means that if I would have `String y = "abc"; String x = new String(y); x = x + y` then I would have only 3 objects?

Answer (score 2):

4 objects will be created.

String are `unmodifiable` so every time you concatenate them a new object will be created

in the case of `"xyz"` in `new String("xyz");` you first create "xyz" object then pass it into a new object (String) so, there are two objects here

```
new String("xyz") <--there are two objects 
"abc"   <-- kinda obvious
x + y  <-- String are unmodifiable thus this is a new object
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually.. String pool works when there are same values for both the strings.

For example, if we have String s1="abc" and s2="abc", then both s1 and s2 will point to same memory reference (or an object).

In the above case, 3 objects will be created

1. for x varible on heap
2. for y variable on stack
3. for x+y expression on heap

Answer (score 0):

Yes the code will create 4 objects

```
String x = new String("xyz"); // object#1 : xyz and Object #2: new String
String y = "abc";             // Object#3 : abc
x = x + y;                    // object#4 : xyzabc
```